# How does inetd know which process to send incoming data to?

Tags: c, xinetd, inetd

I'm trying to replace a inetd/xinetd service by a standalone one. 
What is the simplest I can do this? Is there some standard code to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does inetd know which process to send incoming data to

It spawns it (typically using `fork()` followed by `exec*()`), so it has the process-id.

> Is there some standard code to get started?

What about [`xinetd`'s sources](https://github.com/xinetd-org/xinetd)?

Comment: Found some at www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/Projects/lab01/ssl_echo/

Comment: @user2059893: I added the link to xinetd's source repository to my answer.

Comment: I was actually looking for something event-based (no spawns, no threads), and preferably simple. The nginx code looks promising.